# Filtering duplicate strings that are not identical

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<body style="color:#000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #FFCC99; ">
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("X","X","X","X");
$temp='x';

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value FROM list ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['value'] !== $temp)
    {
        echo $row['value'] . "<br>";
        $temp=$row['value'];
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<body>
```

And this is the output.

```
[24.07.2014](22:19:11): NAVI BESS cu ip 93.78.10.222:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.116:27015
[24.07.2014](22:18:45): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.100:27015
[24.07.2014](22:18:44): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.103:27015
[24.07.2014](22:18:34): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.116:27015
[24.07.2014](22:18:22): czar cu ip 62.72.184.155:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.100:27015
[24.07.2014](22:17:58): AdeLyn*FcRmA cu ip 109.97.251.181:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.103:27015
[24.07.2014](22:17:43): AdeLyn*FcRmA cu ip 109.97.251.181:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.116:27015
[24.07.2014](22:16:59): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.100:27015
[24.07.2014](22:16:04): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.103:27015
[24.07.2014](22:15:56): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.116:27015
[24.07.2014](22:15:44): |TGBR| C4RTM4M cu ip 201.83.208.254:27005 trimis catre 89.33.242.100:27015
[24.07.2014](22:11:48): petike888 cu ip 62.77.206.205:52014 trimis catre 89.33.242.103:27015
```

Obiously my rough method doesn't work because of the time being different. It's too late now for me to change the sql structure, so is there any way I could check the strings and ignore the dates?

I have very basic php knowledge coming from general coding knowledge, I guess I could compare each cell of the string starting from the last and skip the last ones, but from where do I start the if statement? The max lenght of the data, which is 200? Is there some kind of function to get the current lenght of a string? Would this cause huge load times and usage for tens of thousands of lines?

Edit:: also, I don't want to get completely unique strings, i'd really like if I could show one of these lines once per day, so also analyze the date

Adding separate rows for time, date and string would be the last resort

Comment: You can use regex in order to remove the dates and then compare. Or split the string by `:`, remove the first occurance and make a string again.

Comment: you could try something like `group by substr(value, 1, 10)` as well. it won't be particularly efficient, but would give you per-date groups.

Comment: if you have such a big text in 1 column you're doing something wrong already, specially as it seems a log for something. You should have 2 columns for the ip/port 1 for the username and one for the date and then you can easily search around it.

Comment: I agree with you. The reason there's one big string is because there's a different platform adding the data, and I wanted it to be able to control everything the website prints, for example if there's a completely different string, and didn't want to go trough the whole hassle of detecting specific signals from the website to replace the text, or add new rules for new messages.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it too late to change the sql query?

If the timestamp is a standard length (as ita ppears to be), just do a substring.

Doing it at the SQL level allows you to do a distinct which is typically a cheaper operation for RDBMS.

```
 Select Distinct Substring(value, 25) As value
 FROM   list 
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: won't print anything anymore, also reply to the edited stuff, it is standard lenght, at least it will be for 8000 years

Comment: wouldn't it be len(value)-25?)  (it's # of characters not stopping position I thought) and perhaps 23 instead of 25.

Comment: Try without the length altogether.

Comment: still not working - the new version now prints everything without time / date, but duplicates are still there

Comment: Oh you're using an associative result.,. you need to name it proeprly